# How to add customized Color to Kotlin Multiplatform Compose?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

For each customized color, i want to specify rgb values for both light and dark mode.

Is that possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at this library here:**
https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources

It's fully multiplatform compatible, so you don't need to write any platform specific logic, or interfaces.

You will need **ksp plugin** to compile your colors, fonts, images, strings, or any other resources into the appropriate target folders.

https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources?tab=readme-ov-file#example-9---pass-colors